# disable nfs pruning in vagrant

Tags: ruby, configuration, vagrant, nfs

most recently (not sure why) vagrant (1.8.1) started asking for a root password.
however at work no root privileges are given to us (no sodoer)

I am looking for a way to tell vargant to stop the nfs pruning all together

sadly the [documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/vagrant_settings.html) does not say how to modify this particular flag and I don't know ruby much
the [code](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/plugins/synced_folders/nfs/action_cleanup.rb) gives away that there should be a flag but can't figure out to put the "false" in there

I intend to disable NFS or skip that part all together. so both would be welcome.

my starting point is my `~/.vagrant.d/Vagrantfile`

```rb
Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
    config.vagrant.host :nfs_prune => false
end
```

error message is: **`Pruning invalid NFS exports. Administrator privileges will be required...`**

PS: no, I do not use nfs in my shared folders

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should be able to disable by using the [`config.nfs.functional = false`](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/nfs.html#functional)

> `functional` (bool) - Defaults to true. If false, then NFS will not be
>   used as a synced folder type. If a synced folder specifically requests
>   NFS, it will error.

vagrantfile can be loaded from multiple sources, see [LOAD ORDER AND MERGING](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/)

> Vagrant actually loads a series of Vagrantfiles, merging the settings
>   as it goes. This allows Vagrantfiles of varying level of specificity
>   to override prior settings. Vagrantfiles are loaded in the order shown
>   below. Note that if a Vagrantfile is not found at any step, Vagrant
>   continues with the next step.
>
> 1. Vagrantfile packaged with the box that is to be used for a given
>      machine.
> 2. Vagrantfile in your Vagrant home directory (defaults to
>      `~/.vagrant.d`). This lets you specify some defaults for your system
>      user.
> 3. Vagrantfile from the project directory. This is the Vagrantfile
>      that you will be modifying most of the time.

As you mentioned you already check point 3 and 2, check the Vagrantfile from the particular box (if any)

Comment: far after 5 minutes after hitting enter:
sadly this didn't do the job.

again this not a misconfiguration of the particular vagrant files but some awkward global configuration error shown up only recently 
btw. removing the whole .vagrant.d directory didn't do the job either .


PS: 
if there is: please refer to the documentation providing info about these config fields

Comment: does it happen for your specific box only or with any box ?

Comment: however your Answer helped me to prevent that problem. 

I used the "ancient" vagrant setup  with correctly existing sudoers configuration to clean the NFS mess up  and then stated in the global vagrantfile  that nfs is disabled

Comment: it did happen with any box .. because i was using a newer vagrant then what the company sudoers was confuigured for .. therfore the vagrant only worked half and when i started a box WITH nfs required it misconfigured things the new vagrant wasn't ALLOWED to fix

Comment: now it will state: "The synced folder type 'nfs' is reporting as unusable for
your current setup. Please verify you have all the proper
prerequisites for using this shared folder type and try again."

this is what it should do